# Google material design in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Does codenameone has support for Google material design,if yes help me with a sample code on how to use (both icon and font) it in my app.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every element of Material design is supported but the fonts (roboto) etc. will be used when you pick the native: fonts in the Designer tool.

You can also use all the material design icons using the `FontImage` class see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html

There are quite a few other things but the question is a bit vague.